# Determining the flow of the field $(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2+z^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2+z^2},\frac{z}{x^2+y^2+z^2})$ out from $K : 2 \leq x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, divergence-operator

> I'm asked to determine the flow of the field $$\left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2+z^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2+z^2},\frac{z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)$$ out from $$K : 2 \leq x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 3.$$

**My attempt**:

What is relevant to the question is how much flow is produced $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 3.$

I performed the substitution:
$$\begin{cases}x = r\sin{\theta}\cos{\phi}\\
y = r\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}\\
z = r\cos{\theta}\end{cases}$$

where E : $0\leq r \leq \sqrt{3}, \quad 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi, \quad 0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi.$

The divergence of the field is equal to

$$\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\frac{1}{r^2}$$

I use Gauss's theorem:

$$\iint_{\partial K}(F\cdot n)dS = \iiint_K(divF)dxdydz$$
$$= \iiint_E \left(\frac{1}{r^2}\cdot r^2\sin{\theta}\right)drd\phi d\theta = \sqrt{3}\cdot 2\pi \cdot \int_0^\pi \sin{\theta}d\theta = \sqrt{3}\cdot 2\pi \cdot (-1-(-1)) = 0$$

**The answer** is supposed to be $4\pi(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2})$.

**What am I doing wrong and how would I solve this?**

Comment: Isn't it $\sqrt{2}\leq r\leq\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: Also, the integral of the sine between $0$ and $\pi$ is not 0.

Comment: Flow is more commonly named flux fyi

Comment: @dezdichado Yeah I don't get that part of the question. Isn't flux also produced when $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 2$ and I would need to account for that?

Comment: @D.Thomine, Wow I can't believe I made that mistake. I solved it now, thanks.

Comment: @Math_QED Thank you.

Comment: Also, some latex for you: tripple integrals: iiint, double integrals: iint. I also changed some other things. Have a look at the edit. You might learn something useful :)